# Setting "Always on Visible Workspace" does not work

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, workspaces

As I stated in the title, Always on Visible Workspace does not work.
It used to, but I think that plugging another monitor (via HDMI) changed some options and now, after unplugging - this option does not work.
I've found http://gregcor.com/2011/05/07/fix-du...es-are-broken/ but I don't have desktop/gnome/shell config, so there was no help.

Do you have some ideas what might have happened?

Description: Ubuntu 13.10

Move to other workspace makes current window dissapear - so I suppose it exists in some other (virtual?) workspace, that actually doesn't exist. So I think something in wrong with workspaces (!).

But Ctrl+Shift+Right/Left/Up/Down works all right. It moves window to other workspace. So I suppose the application that moves by "Ctrl+Shift+Right/Left/Up/Down" has a proper settings while window manager does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same issue.  The following worked for me.

Open up CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm).  Go to the 'Workarounds' section -> Window stickyness (bottom of General Tab).  Select/enable the checkbox next to 'Make "on all desktops" windows "sticky"'.